# Javascript if statement using method from an external file

Tags: javascript

I have multiple pages with identical form validation, so I have moved it to an external js file. My call to the method (validateFormFill() is in file GARIValidateFormFill.js) within the external file is

```
$("#submitForm").click(function(){
    if (validateFormFill()) {
        //code
    }               
});
```

When I now call validateFormFill, nothing happens. I do have my js file properly linked within my jsp.

What do I need to do to read the external file in my if statement?

**Edit**
Here is more per request.

My file is linked properly: `<script    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/javascript/GARIValidateFormFill.js"></script>`

Within my external file I have:

```
     function validateFormFill() {

            // Make sure at least one file is entered
            var blnAtLeastOneFileSelected = false;
            for (var i=0; i < $('#numOfFiles').val(); i++) {
                var index = i+1;
                // Reset the amount to contain no commas prior to submitting the form.
                if ($('#txtFile' + index).is(':checked')) {
                    blnAtLeastOneFileSelected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ( ! blnAtLeastOneFileSelected ) {
                alert("ERROR! Please select at least one file before submitting the form!");
                return false;
            }

            var ckdt = checkDate($('#txtReportDate').val())
            if ( ckdt == false ) {
                return false;
            }

            if($('#txtVersionNum').val() == "00.00" || $('#txtVersionNum').val().length == 0) {
                alert("ERROR! Version No. must be entered before submitting form!");
                $('#txtVersionNum').focus();
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: First of all if validateFormFill() is a method then you should have something like obj.validateFormFill()... if it's a function then your fine to use validateFormFill() the way you have... 2nd post the code for your method/function validateFormFill() so we can see it.

Comment: Could be a number of factors. The external JS isn't loading (check the console). It, or another file, contains an error (check the console.) The function is out of scope. (Will show up as an error in the console once you try to invoke the function.)

Comment: Confirm all the form id are same and u have jquery in every file

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the reference in a `<script>` tag before the `validateFormFill()` is executed.

Without much knowledge of `validateFormFill`, I am assuming you're looking for something more like...

```
<script src="path/to/GARIValidateFormFill.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#submitForm").click(function(){
        if (validateFormFill()) {
            //code
        }               
    });
</script>
```

[Script Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp)

Comment: Also he must make sure that his function is properly exposed to the global variable, eg.: not inside a `$(function() {})` block.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I was missing a closing `}` in my external file

Comment: Using a linter like [jslint](http://jslint.com/) or [jshint](http://jshint.com/) can help find this kind of bug quickly before they drive you crazy ;-)